# I cannot stream messages from firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am learning Flutter chat app from Angela YU
but this part of code is just like as she wrote but for me not working and it has lots of errors

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                ),
              );
            }
            final messages = snapshot.data?.docs;
            List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
            for (var message in messages!) {
              final messageText = message.data['text'];
              final messageSender = message.data['sender'];
              final messageWidget =
                  Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
              messageWidget.add(messageWidget);
            }
            return Column(
              children: [
                messageWidgets,
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
```

here is the errors :

> ```
> lib/screens/chat_screen.dart:72:53: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object? Function()'.
> ```
>
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'. Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
>   final messageText = message.data['text'];
>   ^ lib/screens/chat_screen.dart:73:55: Error: The operator '[]' isn't
>   defined for the class 'Object? Function()'.
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'. Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
>   final messageSender = message.data['sender'];
>   ^ lib/screens/chat_screen.dart:76:35: Error: The method 'add' isn't
>   defined for the class 'Text'.
> - 'Text' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text.dart'). Try
>   correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a
>   method named 'add'.
>   messageWidget.add(messageWidget);
>   ^^^ lib/screens/chat_screen.dart:80:23: Error: A value of type
>   'List' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'.
> - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
> - 'Text' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text.dart').
> - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
>   messageWidgets,
>   ^ lib/screens/chat_screen.dart:67:24: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Widget' doesn't
>   allow null.
> - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
>   builder: (context, snapshot) {
>   ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code like this

```dart
            final messages = snapshot.data?.docs;
            List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
            for (var message in messages) {
              var data = message.data() as Map; // add Typecast 
              final messageText = data['text'];
              final messageSender = data['sender'];
              final messageWidget = Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
              messageWidgets.add(messageWidget); // you have to add item to list
            }
            return Column(
              children: messageWidgets // your list should assign to children
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming up as a result of breaking changes in the version upgrades to the Firestore library.

See https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration/

## Solution:

Change this

```dart
final messageText = message.data['text'];
```

to this:

```dart
final messageText = (message.data as Map<String, dynamic>)['text'];
```

Answer (score 0):

after opening the curly braces {
just add this code

```
          var data = message.data() as Map;
```

and change the existing code to

```
          final messageText = data['text'];
          final messageSender = data['sender']
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering about this errors in **2023-24**

Change your code to the following as the old methods are now deprecated, And dart has made a lot of changes for nullable types since dart 2.

Your **for loop** should look like this according to the latest versions of dart.

```
for (var message in messages) {
                final messageText = message.get('text');
                final messageSender = message.get('sender');
                final messageWidget =
                    Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
                messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
              }
```

the get() method is used in the latest versions instead of the older one.

You  have to also return something if the snapshot.data() condition is false.
insert this outside your condition:

```
return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
```